Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined at firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:1
i am implementing the firebase web push notification in the angular application .
i am getting the error
Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined at firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:1

i have mentioned the below importscript at the top of the file too
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js");
firebase version is "10.12.2"
i have registerd with the service worker too and i am getting the log
"Service Worker registered with scope: http://localhost:4200/".
even i am getting the FCM token but not notification.
